# Metadata under elastic search index?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have gone through [How Elastic search works](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up) to get high level idea how elastic search works where
I see it keeps the document_id containing it but My question is does it keep exact location(something like line and column number) also in document ?

Comment: What do you mean "does it keep exact location"? The `_id` is actually outside the `_source` field (the fields indexed from the document), though it is stored and accessible and queryable when querying an index. And of course its "location" is kept as it is an essential part of the coordinates of a document (the tuple (index,type,id))

Comment: @asettouf Say i have 10k lines in a document, there is a word "city" in document. I understand that Elastic search index(ESI) will contain the document location but my question will Elastic search index will also keep the location of that word in that document (like "city" is t 9100 line number and column is 200th position)?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, when ES stores a term (after the analysis phase) it also stores the offset in the document (i.e. its position)

See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-options.html

> Analyzed string fields use positions as the default

And the position option on a type:

> Doc number, term frequencies, and term positions (or order) are indexed. Positions can be used for proximity or phrase queries.

Comment: I am not clear what does `term positions` mean ? How it is different from offset ?

Comment: @user3198603 The difference is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#postings-highlighter)."the postings highlighter will be used instead of the plain highlighter".